# MS Access Equivalent for T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, casting, linked-tables

I have a query some thing like this :

```
convert(varchar(7), [DateDelivered], 120) As Month_Delivered
```

This does not seem to work with Access ODBC linked tables. what would be the equivalent for above ?

I  have tried with CSTR , does not seem to work . I am getting error like :

```
Syntax error: missing operator in query expression .
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DateDelivered is date, you would use Format in this case:

```
Format([DateDelivered], "yyyy-mm") As Month_Delivered
```

Comment: @Gustav..This would convert into required date format .Thanks. I would also like to convert into string along with format

Comment: MID(CSTR(Format(DateDelivered,""yyyy-mm"")),1,7). The final thing i require is the combination of both the answers. Thank you guys..

Comment: You really need to learn. Format returns always a string, so applying CStr makes no sense, and what Mid does here, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

your query in access?

if so write

```
mid([DateDelivered],1,7) As Month_Delivered
```

or

```
mid(cstr([DateDelivered]),1,7) As Month_Delivered
```

Comment: @zvi..This would convert to string but would not get the required date format

Comment: Dates should always be handled like dates, not strings, no exception.